# What is best way to setup ReactJS with CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: php, reactjs, cakephp, integration, cakephp-3.0

Am very much familiar with CakePHP and a newbie in ReactJS and looking to implement it with CakePHP 3.x.
Concern to ask what is the best folder structure where we should place the ReactJS.

Options am getting in my mind either one from:

1. Included in `Webroot/MyApp` with index.html
2. Include `Layouts/default.ctp` with only scripts tags in header

I know its good to make it separate and use CakePHP as REST API But its good if I'd take any help from CakePHP features (eg. Sessions, Helpers...) itself. But am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React without issues as a frontend, even with "serverside" generated HTML, by extending helpers etc from Cake.

At least for a start you can place the files inside the webroot folder of cake, but you should consider looking into bundling the front-end if it grows with. eg webpack

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is really old, I just want to add my answer here in case any dev comes here looking for answers.

Currently there's multiple resources available that helps to integrate React with CakePHP framework. Mark story - core developer of CakePHP framework wrote a blog post on how to do that:
http://mark-story.com/posts/view/cakephp-react-and-typescript-application-starter

Here's the skeleton app he has created: https://github.com/markstory/cakephp-typescript-react

You can also use AssetMix plugin which can help you use any front-end tools with CakePHP.
Link to the plugin: https://github.com/ishanvyas22/asset-mix